# show confirm box with custom message in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, cross-browser

I need to show custom error message when user closes the tab.
As of now its showing different default messages based on browsers and I have found a lot of references to do this. I think modern browsers are not supporting this option.

I am using below code in Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) {
   return 'Are you sure you want to leave, cause there are some unsaved changes?';
}
</script>
```

Also tried with Jquery but still its not working

```
$( window ).unload(function() {
 return "Bye now!";
});
```

If there is any other solution will be overriding this one. Please let me know

Comment: I'm pretty sure this won't be possible because it violates some security that a lot of browser vendors deem potentially malicious. Think of ads that open and when you try to close them they show a message saying that closing the tab will do something harmful. Too much potential for evil.

Comment: @dinesh-sns I feel like to say that its because of your maturity that you are approving an answer as the correct one, that doesn't fulfill your desire. I mean you were looking for a way of customizing `beforeunload` message, even though after getting that its impossible to do so, you accepted the not-so-sweet answer! Some guys here not only don't approve, but also downvote correct-but-undesired answers. I'm glad you are not one of them. Good luck & Happy coding Dude!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot override its default message. That string is not controlled by web page so you are not allowed to manipulate it. [As Stated Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)